# Op-Amp Resolution

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, resolution

How to calculate resolution of op-amp? What is the minimum variation required in input voltage for output voltage to vary?In my application the op-amp is connected as an integrator whose positive voltage is a DAC voltage.

Comment: Opamps are **analog** and as such do not have a resolution as like an ADC does. Maybe you mean **noise** ?

Comment: Reminds me of one of my old questions: [Differential input voltage necessary for maximum slew rate in operational amplifiers](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/261408/differential-input-voltage-necessary-for-maximum-slew-rate-in-operational-amplif)

Comment: @FakeMoustache : I have the resolution of DAC (connected to non-inverting input of op-amp). So can I expect the opamp output voltage corresponding to this small DAC voltage? Is there any way to predict the noise (Input offset voltage effect or gain tolerance change) that will appear with required output?

Comment: **1)** Show the actual schematic of what you're talking about. There are many ways to use an opamp and connect it to a DAC. How can I comment on what you do when I have no clue what you're doing ? **2)** I do not like *Can I expect...* questions since it seems you're just **guessing**, hoping your guess is correct and want to hear yes/no. That's not going to happen. You want to design something, then you cannot avoid thinking about what will happen and how things are calculated. I suspect that you still have **a lot** to learn about circuit design, we're not going to teach you that here !

Comment: Than you FakeMoustache. I understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that what is being asked is *what is the minimum amount that an op amp’s output can be changed by varying the input*.  So the diagram below shows the DC output of an op amp, including noise.  I’ve simplified the noise probability distribution to something like a normal distribution.  So the question is what is the minimum possible controllable δV?

[image: Op amp dc output]

Ostensibly there is no such thing as true analogue electronics.  Circuits pass charge (not voltage) in integer units of *e* (1.6×10−19 C), which is the charge on a single electron.  This is especially important with sensitive modern electronics that can count individual electrons, and leads to shot noise as individual electrons fly by.  An op amp is a circuit like any other, it just happens to have a (relatively) standardised configuration.  The minimum output therefore can only be 1 electron.  The ratio of input to output can vary according to the gain setting and noise but cannot be less than 1 electron.

However a single electron does not current make.  From the classic equation of *V = IR*, we can derive:-

[image: equation]

where  *N* = number of electrons, and *t* = time.  *R* is the load, test leads, final output transistor etc.  If we exclude the (so far) hypothetical concept of discrete Planck time, time is a continuous metric.  Similarly for statistical purposes, the electron count *N* becomes a mathematical average which does not have to be an integer. That means that *V* becomes continuous and therefore analogue.  Ergo *δV → 0*.

So, theoretical op amp resolution =  infinite.
Practical  op amp resolution = determined by firstly quantization of your measuring instrument, especially if it has a discrete output /display.  That might be an oscilloscope pixel or the least significant digit on a multi meter.  Secondly, your ability to vary the input voltage with sufficiently small increments.  If your input is from a DAC, it will hypothetically be the DAC’s output resolution, but still limited by your final measuring instrument as above.

The take away is *don’t concern yourself with op amp resolution.  Worry about the other bits of your circuit*.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the minimum variation required in input voltage for output
>   voltage to vary?

For every op-amp known to man that is used in a linear application, the smallest variation in the applied input voltage needed to vary the output is exactly zero volts. This is because every op-amp known to man (and operated at a temperature above absolute zero), produces noise and this appears on the output irrespective of the input voltage.

> In my application the op-amp is connected as an integrator

That's a linear application and is subject to what I've just said.

Comment: Can I expect the output voltage of op-amp correponding to the minimum DAC output voltage?

Comment: Is there any way to predict the noises?

Comment: You need to post your schematic with part numbers. On noise there are some fairly simple ways of predicting output noise but again, it requires you to show a schematic ideally.

Comment: I think that you've misunderstood the question. @Manisha is asking what is the minimum change in input voltage to generate a corresponding change in output voltage.  That's why he uses the term resolution. He's not talking about random fluctuations.

Comment: @paul so how would you answer this question?

Answer (score 1):

Here is example of opamp noise, given 1milliVolt input, closed-loop gain of 1,000x and using an opamp chosen for low noise of 1nanoVolt/rtHz. Notice the 1milliVolt input, the low bandwidth (set by opamp) and low Rnoise, together produce 78dB signal-noise-ratio SNR.

The output noise of 42 microVolts RMS has 3dB bandwidth of 1KHz, set by intersection of ClosedLoop Gain of 60dB with the OpenLoop Gain curve, at 1KHz.
[image]

How can we improve the "resolution"? Reduce the noise. Given fixed OpAmp noise density of 1 nanoVolt/rootHertz (thus 1KHz BW produces 1nV * sqrt(1,000) == 31.5nV rms total noise, integrated DC---1KHz), our remaining knob-and-lever is to reduce the bandwidth. Below we show the result with 100Hertz LPF. Note the resistor is large, to isolate the Cap from the OpAmp, so the OpAmp does not  oscillate.

Result? SNR improves from 78 to 88dB; we expect that ---- 10dB ---- because we reduced the bandwidth exactly 10:1 and that reduces the noise power exactly 10:1 and reduced the noise voltage exactly sqrt(10).

[image]

Comment: What did you learn?